# PHPStorm в терминале сдвигает строку

Tags: phpstorm, terminal

Может было у кого-то такое в PhpStorm, баг это или что не пойму, что когда в терминале вводишь команду следующая строка идет не на новой строке а сильно сдвигается. 
Собственно проблема на изображении.

[image: хрень какая-то]